# ERROR in Error: [class] and [className] bindings cannot be used on the same element simultaneously

Tags: angular, class, ivy, angular9, angular-ivy

I have updated Angular to version 9, but during compilation getting this error -

```
ERROR in Error: [class] and [className] bindings cannot be used on the same element simultaneously
at StylingBuilder.registerClassInput (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14096:27)
at StylingBuilder.registerInputBasedOnName (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14056:36)
at StylingBuilder.registerBoundInput (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14033:36)
at D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18176:57
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.visitElement (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18175:28)
at Element.visit (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4442:28)
at visitAll (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4638:40)
at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.visitElement (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18348:13)
at Element.visit (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4442:28)
at visitAll (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4638:40)
at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17828:13)
at D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18401:60
at D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17838:81
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (D:\SVN\NCPV2_Repo_22jun\trunk\NCPV2\ncpapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17838:37)
```

I don't have any binding like `[className]`

But still getting this issue.